# wrapper cookbook adding attribute to resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to change the default behavior of the IIS cookbook that uses the windows_feature resource to install the features. It is within a loop like below:

```
node['iis']['components'].each do |feature|
  windows_feature feature do
    action :install
  end
end
```

I am trying to get the wrapper cookbook to add an attribute to this resource. Such as:

```
w = resource(:windows_feature => "feature")
w.source "path_to_source_files"
```

Of course this is not working because "feature" is not defined. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question. It seems that if the cookbook doesn't allow for the flexibility to adjust specific attributes of a resource (i.e. the attributes weren't used/defined), then you simply depend on the cookbook to access its available attributes, but exclude 'include_recipe'.

**Original wrapper cookbook:**

*metadata.rb*

```
depends 'iis'
```

*default.rb*

```
include_recipe 'iis::default'

w = resource(:windows_feature => 'feature')
w.source 'path_to_source_files'
```

**Fixed wrapper cookbook:**

*metadata.rb*

```
depends 'iis'
```

*default.rb*

```
node['iis']['components'].each do |feature|
 windows_feature feature do
  action :install
  source 'path_to_source_files'
 end
end
```